# dplyr conditional count function in R language

Tags: r

In the following code, the 2rd payment for item b is zero value. Using the pipe `%>%`, is possible to show the count for item b as 2 not 3 since there is no payment for b at the 2rd payment?

```
df <-data.frame("item" = c("a","b", "b","a","b"), "payment" = c(10,20,0,40,30) )

df_sum <-
  df %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(payment),
            totalcount =n())
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out rows you don't want. E.g., if you don't want to count rows where `payment = 0`, you can use `filter`:

```
df %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  filter(payment > 0) %>% 
  summarise(total = sum(payment),
            totalcount =n())
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  item  total totalcount
  <fct> <dbl>      <int>
1 a      50.0          2
2 b      50.0          2
```

Comment: Thanks. I add one column named 'due'. I need to count payment and due. and keep item b pay count as 2.df <- data.frame("item" = c("a","b", "b","a","b"), "payment" = c(10,20,0,40,30), "due" = c(4,6,8,9,5) )

df_sum <-
  df %>%
  group_by(item) %>%
  summarise(total_pay = sum(payment),
            total_due = sum(due),
            pay_count =n(),
            du_count =n()
            )

Comment: df <- data.frame("item" = c("a","b", "b","a","b"), "payment" = c(10,20,0,40,30), "due" = c(4,6,8,9,5) )

df_sum <-
     df %>%
     group_by(item) %>%
     summarise(total_pay = sum(payment),
               total_due = sum(due),
               pay_count =n(),
               du_count =n()
              )

Comment: I'm not in front of R atm, but you could change the `n()` bit to `pay_count = 
 sum(payment >0)` and `due_count  = sum(due > 0)` or something.